# Euler's paper for the theorem $ e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta) $?

Tags: mathematicians

Which is Leonard Euler's Paper where he proves this central result? The term 'complex number' does not seem to have been used by him. I'm hoping someone could link me to some page in the Euler archive.

Comment: For the term "complex number", see [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/c.html) : **COMPLEX NUMBER.**: "Most of the 17th and 18th century writers spoke of $a + bi$ as an *imaginary quantity*. The term *complex number* was used in English in 1856 by William Rowan Hamilton."

Comment: This older question seems closely related: [Euler's first proof of $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/4907/eulers-first-proof-of-eix-cosxi-sinx)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I wonder if you would have any thoughts on [How did the definition of complex logarithm evolve since Cotes (1682-1716)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2395338/284619)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears at the end of $\S\,138$ in *Introductio* (1748).  In Blanton's translation this appears on page 112, line 5.

Comment: I think [Introductio](https://books.google.it/books?id=_zpRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA104) (1748)...